# Serilog.Settings.Configuration is not working when it is referenced as package

Tags: c#, serilog, appsettings

I am getting really strange behaviour trying to configure **Serilog** using **appsettings.json**.

It only works when I add **Serilog.Settings.Configuration** to my project using Add Project Reference.
When **Serilog.Settings.Configuration** (3.2.0) is installed as package I am getting Exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot create instance of type 'Serilog.Formatting.ITextFormatter' because it is either abstract or an interface.'
```

Here is code example that I am using to parse configuration:

```
    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"}.json", true)
        .Build();

    var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
        .CreateLogger();
```

Here is config that I am using:

```
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Debug",
        "System": "Debug"
      }
    },
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "formatter": {
            "type": "Serilog.Templates.ExpressionTemplate, Serilog.Expressions",
            "template": "[{@t:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} {@l:u3}] {#if CorrelationId is not null}{CorrelationId} | {#end}{@m:lj}\n{@x}"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Here is an example of not working project file (Serilog.Settings.Configuration is PackageReference):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>0718b2b6-70cb-4a9b-9c43-30625d246f61</UserSecretsId>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
    <AssemblyName>SomeName</AssemblyName>
    <RootNamespace>SomeNamespace</RootNamespace>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.14.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Expressions" Version="3.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="3.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
    
</Project>
```

Here is an example of working project file (Serilog.Settings.Configuration is ProjectReference):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>0718b2b6-70cb-4a9b-9c43-30625d246f61</UserSecretsId>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
    <AssemblyName>SomeName</AssemblyName>
    <RootNamespace>SomeNamespace</RootNamespace>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.14.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Expressions" Version="3.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\serilog-settings-configuration-dev\src\Serilog.Settings.Configuration\Serilog.Settings.Configuration.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

What am I missing?
It looks like Serilog.Settings.Configuration is ignored when it is referenced as package, right?
How can I fix that?

Comment: Do you need a specific feature or fix implemented in `Serilog.Settings.Configuration` **3.2.0**? If not, then you don't need to reference it as a package because `Serilog.AspNetCore` already includes `Serilog.Settings.Configuration` - except a prior version **3.1.0**

Comment: @C.AugustoProiete: yes, new feature was added: ability to provide formatter with arguments (for example ExpressionTemplate in my config file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Update 2021-10-11*: [v3.3.0 has been released](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration/releases/tag/v293) and includes the feature you're trying to use ([Support of constructor parameters](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration/pull/281)).

---

The feature you're trying to use ([Support of constructor parameters](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration/pull/281)) has not yet been released and as such is not present in the `Serilog.Settings.Configuration` `3.2.0` package which is why you get that error... This feature is [planned to be released with `3.3.0`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration/pull/282) at date TBD.

You alternatives are:

1.) Use a pre-release package (e.g. `3.3.0-dev-00291`)

```
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="3.3.0-dev-00291" />
```

2.) Compile it from source, as you demonstrated in your question

3.) Wait until `3.3.0` is out

Comment: Thank you. README.md is confusing a little bit: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration. Looking at section "Complex parameter value binding" I assumed that this feature has already been implemented.

Comment: *Update 2021-10-11*: [v3.3.0 has been released](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration/releases/tag/v293)

Answer (score 2):

I know this particular issue was fixed by the release of `Serilog.Settings.Configuration` v3.3.0.  However, if you've encountered this same error since the release of v3.3.0, as I did, the following might be useful:

In addition to installing NuGet package `Serilog.Settings.Configuration` you also need package `Serilog.Expressions`.

This wasn't clear to me from the various blog posts and examples I saw that used expression templates in the appsettings.json file.